# Error F# - c# async calls : converting Threading.Tasks.Task<MyType> to Async<'a>

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, f#-async

When I try to call an async method that is in C# library from my F# code.
I get the following compilation error.

> This expression was expected to have type Async<'a> but here has type Threading.Thread.Tasks.Task

`SendMessageAsync` is in C# library and returns `Threading.Thread.Tasks.Task<MyType>`

```
let sendEmailAsync message = 
    async {
        let! response = client.SendMessageAsync(message)
        return response
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For converting between `Task<'T>` and `Async<'T>` there is a built-in `Async.AwaitTask` function.

To convert between a plain `Task` and `Async<unit>` you can create a helper function:

```
type Async with
    member this.AwaitPlainTask (task : Task) =
        task.ContinueWith(fun t -> ())
        |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
let sendEmailAsync message = 
    async {
        let! response = Async.AwaitPlainTask <|client.SendMessageAsync(message)
        return response
    }
```

Of course, in this case, the response can't be anything other than `()`, so you might as well just write:

```
let sendEmailAsync message = Async.AwaitPlainTask <|client.SendMessageAsync(message)
```

Comment: many thanks! I can't find Async.AwaitPlainTask instead i have Async.AwaitTask.

Comment: aah, my mistake. I just found the type you created.

Comment: @NishantNidhiKumar Yes, that one isn't built in to the core library but it's often useful to create.