# Xamarin F# to C# async call: correct modern way

Tags: xamarin, f#, c#-to-f#, f#-async

I'm trying to call C# Async function synchronously from F# code in Xamarin. The original C# code looks like (this is the Plugin.BLE target device service discovery):

```
            {
                var service = await _connectedDevice.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid);
                if (service != null)
                {
                    var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(characteristicGuid);
                    if (characteristic != null)
                    {
```

If I'm using recommended F# primitive

```
module Async =
    let inline AwaitPlainTask (task: Task) = 
       task.ContinueWith(fun t -> ())
       |> Async.AwaitTask
```

The following code:

```
async {
         let! service = Async.AwaitPlainTask <|d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid)
         let! characteristic = Async.AwaitPlainTask <|service.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristicGuid)
...
```

could not be compiled because 'The field, constructor or member 'GetCharacteristicAsync' is not defined.'. Seems F# could not correctly determine or convert type after AwaitPlainTask.

If I'm trying to do it in the regular way, e.g.:

```
async {
         let serviceTask = d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid)

         serviceTask.Wait()

         let tsk = serviceTask.Result.ToString()
```

the serviceTask.Result is always null. The same result (null) happens for

```
let! service = d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

too. C# code is working, so basically the problem is with how it's called from F#.  I think I misunderstood something here, what is the correct way to deal with this type of constructions?

P.S.: It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476042/error-f-c-sharp-async-calls-converting-threading-tasks-taskmytype-to-asyn) question, because that probably is outdated and no longer works (at least on Xamarin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are using here `AwaitPlainTask`, looks like it's a convenience function to deal with `Task`. However there is a standard way of dealing with `Task<T>` in F# `async` computation expressions. You should be using `Async.AwaitTask`, along with `let!`, like this:

```
async {
    // Removing back-pipes as they are often more confusing that useful
    let! service = d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid) |> Async.AwaitTask
    let! characteristic = service.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristicGuid) |> Async.AwaitTask
...
```

What you are doing otherwise is the equivalent in C# of casting `Task<T>` to `Task` and trying to await it:

```
var result = await ((Task)d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid))
```

which wouldn't compile in C#, however in F# we have the `unit` type, which actually is really handy as you don't a proliferation of types and overloads of generic code.

It's also worth noting that you can probably delete `AwaitPlainTask` as it now is an overload of the build in `Async.AwaitTask` since F# 4.0, for example:

```
let waitOneSecond () = async {
    // Use do! not let! when you aren't using the result
    do! Task.Delay(1000) |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

I've had a look at `Plugin.BLE` and it looks like awaitng `GetServiceAsync` can return `null` as you say, it is the design of the library.

To handle this, we could wrap the result in an `Option` type and use that as a safe way to access it after. For example:

```
let! service = d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid) |> Async.AwaitTask
let service = service |> Option.ofObj
match service with
| Some s -> let! characteristic = s.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristicGuid) |> Async.AwaitTask
            ()
| None ->   ()
```

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question, ```let! service = d.GetServiceAsync(serviceGuid) |> Async.AwaitTask``` returns null for the service. (C# code in the same situation works)

Comment: @Darkkey If this answer be helpful , remember to mark it :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT this answer is not helpful unfortunately, it suggests the way I've already tried (and included in question). As I've mentioned in the comment above, it does not work (service become null). It's not the library problem, as equivalent C# code is working.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I will update my answer in a few hours.